# Using common_schema library not able to parse the json array values

Tags: mysql, common-schema

We are using this common_schema library in mysql 5.6 to extract the values from json array. The format is given below. But it returns the NULL value. So, can you please help us out how to parse the json array using common_schema.

```
select common_schema.extract_json_value('"batter":
[
     { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
     { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
     { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
     { "id": "1004", "type": "Devils Food" }
]','/id');
```

Expected output should be saved in table as

```
   id    type
  1001  Regular
  1002  Chocolate
  1003  Blueberry
  1004  Devils Food
```

Please let us know how we can achieve this parsing.

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: Please make sure you use extract_json_value with a valid json cause this is not a valid one.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. It is likely you need to add curly brackets around the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Directly it seems not so easy to get what you need.

An option to obtain a single value is:

```sql
SET @`json` := '
{
    "batter":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devils Food" }
        ]
}
';

SELECT
    `common_schema`.`extract_json_value`(@`json`,'descendant-or-self::id[1]') `id`,
    `common_schema`.`extract_json_value`(@`json`,'descendant-or-self::type[1]') `type`;

+------+---------+
| id   | type    |
+------+---------+
| 1001 | Regular |
+------+---------+
1 row in set (0,04 sec)
```